# Why php divides date instead of saving it as string?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database table that has a VARCHAR field storing a date in dd/mm/yyyy format.

I have a situation where I need to extract that date to a variable and then save it in a different table (which has a different structure than the first one).

So I do this:

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from shares") or die(mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$date_old=$row['last_update'];    //date in dd/mm/yyyy format
```

Then when I try to insert `$date_old` into the other table, instead of inserting the date, PHP actually performs a mathematical division operation on it! So instead of saving 14/03/2012, it divides 14 by 3 and then by 2012 and stores 0.0023 in the database.

Surely there is a way to stop this from happening using a built-in function (without removing the slashes from the string and then putting them back in before insertion)?

Comment: if the issue is with the `INSERT` query, why do you show us the `SELECT` query? and why are you fetching `*` when you just need to use the `last_update` column? And why do you make two queries instead of just using `INSERT … SELECT?`

Comment: what are data types of the source field and destination field?

Comment: data types are both varchar, you're right about the insert query being the problem, I had forgotten to add single quotes around the variable (as Karoly suggested below). works now, thank you.

Comment: Gordon, I'm using two queries because the insert query inserts variables not only from this table, but quite a few other variables too, so it's cleaner this way.

Comment: If they answered your question, you should mark it as answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When doing insert put the values in single quotes: `" ... last_update = '$date' ... "`, otherwise mysql will do the calculations.

Note: for storing dates use the [date type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html).

Comment: Wow, what a blunder. I'm saving a bunch of variables to that other table, forgot to add quotes to this one. Works now. Thanks!

Comment: I actually gave an example for update but I see you got the point ;)

Answer (score 0):

That is because, it turns out into an expression `14/03/2012`

Escape the values using quotes.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO anothertable (data) VALUES('$olddate');";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it with quotes and make it mysql format i.e

```
$date_new=explode("/", $date_old); //date in dd/mm/yyyy
$my_date=$date_new[2]."/".$date_new[1]."/".$date_new[0];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO myTable (FirstName, last_update, Age)VALUES ('Peter', '".$my_date."',35)");
```

Answer (score 0):

In general (apart of quoting the value as it's a string):
Why not use the DATE Format type that will store a date in the format YYYY-MM-DD (as it is the type that's made for dates!):

[mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)